# Comparing bytes in a ByteBuffer

Tags: java, arrays, bytebuffer

I have a `byte` array in Java of size 4, which I am trying to put the first two bytes of into  `ByteBuffer`.

Here is how I am doing it:

```
byte[] array = new byte[4];
ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
buff.put(array, 0, 2);
```

What's wrong with my code?

EDIT:

```
byte[] currRecord = new byte[4];
byte[] leftRecord = new byte[4];
// Code that populates the records
ByteBuffer currKey = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
currKey = currKey.put(currRecord, 0, 2);
ByteBuffer leftKey = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
leftKey = leftKey.put(leftRecord, 0, 2);
```

Then I am trying to compare both `ByteBuffers` as follows:

```
if (currKey.compareTo(leftKey) >= 0)
    return;
```

My comparison is always wrong. When debugging, I am pretty sure `currRecord` and `leftRecord` have the right values. The `ByteBuffer`s also have the right values (according to the debugger). What is the problem here?

Comment: The code you posted will work fine (although there is nothing interesting in `array`). Post your real code.

Comment: Q: "What's wrong with my code?" A: "It's wrong!?!" Tell us what is happening and what you're expecting to happen. The code is simple enough that if you sit down and try to explain to us what is the problem, then you will most likely figure out the solution (and you may not need to post an SO question).

Comment: To echo Link -- what makes you think something is wrong with your code? What is it doing (or not doing) that is different from what you expect?

Comment: Well I thought it was the problem and you just pointed out it was right! See the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `compareTo` compares the *remaining bytes* of the buffers. Therefore you must first `flip()` both buffers before the comparison.

Without the `flip` you will compare the bytes[2..3] in each buffer. Because you did not write those bytes, they all will be zero. With the `flip` you will compare the bytes[0..1] which contains the data you have written from the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You still haven't said what results you're looking for. The code you have posted worked fine for me

```
byte[] currRecord = new byte[4];
byte[] leftRecord = new byte[4];
// Code that populates the records
ByteBuffer currKey = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
currKey = currKey.put(currRecord, 0, 2);
ByteBuffer leftKey = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
leftKey = leftKey.put(leftRecord, 0, 2);

if (currKey.compareTo(leftKey) == 0)
    System.out.println("equal");
else
    System.out.println("not equal");
```

//outputs "equal"

Were you expecting this to *not* be equal? If so, I don't see why. There's nothing in your code that would explicitly say *these aren't equal*.

Note - Calling `flip()` on both buffers will still produce "equal".

Comment: No it doesn't. Calling `flip()` fixed it.

Comment: @Nayefc lol.. with the code you provided, there is no difference if you call `flip()` or not on the two bytebuffers. I tested it several times.

Comment: Me too - and it did work :) Used a debugger and traced the objects in the heap.